# Org Babel execute bash via ssh on non-default port; `(wrong-type-argument number-or-marker-p nil)`

Tags: org-babel, tramp, bash

## Problem

In an org file, I have a source code block containing bash code that I want to run on a remote machine:

```
* test
  :PROPERTIES:
  :header-args:bash: :dir /ssh:skid@127.0.0.1#2221:
  :END:

  #+begin_src bash 
    whoami
  #+end_src
```

Placing Mark inside the block and pressing `C-c C-c`, I expect an output block containing the username on the remote(`skid`) to appear below, but I get an error: `(wrong-type-argument number-or-marker-p nil)`

## Question

I'm a bit lost on how and why this fails, so; Any ideas on what goes wrong?

Pointers on how to interpret the trace, for a lisp noob, will be very appreaciated.

## Details

### SSH server and tramp seems fine on it's own

This opens the remote folder in dired mode without errors:

`emacs -nw '/ssh:skid@localhost#2221:/home/skid/10.10.10.198/'`

### Backtrace

The backtrace (from doing `M-: (setq debug-on-error t)` before the above `C-c C-c`) is too long to include, so the first few lines are below, and the complete one is on [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/mtWvWK9h):

```lisp
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument number-or-marker-p nil)
  <(0 nil)
  (if (< 0 (file-attribute-size (file-attributes error-file))) (progn (save-current-buffer (set-buffer (get-buffer-create error-buffer)) (let ((pos-from-end (- (point-max) (point)))) (or (bobp) (insert "\f\n")) (format-insert-file error-file nil) (goto-char (- (point-max) pos-from-end))) (current-buffer))))
  (progn (if (< 0 (file-attribute-size (file-attributes error-file))) (progn (save-current-buffer (set-buffer (get-buffer-create error-buffer)) (let ((pos-from-end (- ... ...))) (or (bobp) (insert "\f\n")) (format-insert-file error-file nil) (goto-char (- (point-max) pos-from-end))) (current-buffer)))) (delete-file error-file))
  (if (and error-file (file-exists-p error-file)) (progn (if (< 0 (file-attribute-size (file-attributes error-file))) (progn (save-current-buffer (set-buffer (get-buffer-create error-buffer)) (let ((pos-from-end ...)) (or (bobp) (insert "\f\n")) (format-insert-file error-file nil) (goto-char (- ... pos-from-end))) (current-buffer)))) (delete-file error-file)))
  (let ((input-file (org-babel-temp-file "ob-input-")) (error-file (if error-buffer (org-babel-temp-file "ob-error-") nil)) (shell-file-name (cond ((and (not (file-remote-p default-directory)) (executable-find shell-file-name)) shell-file-name) ((file-executable-p (concat (file-remote-p default-directory) shell-file-name)) shell-file-name) ("/bin/sh"))) exit-status) (if (file-remote-p default-directory) nil (delete-file error-file)) (let ((swap (< start end))) (goto-char start) (push-mark (point) 'nomsg) (write-region start end input-file) (delete-region start end) (setq exit-status (process-file shell-file-name input-file (if error-file (list t error-file) t) nil shell-command-switch command)) (if swap (progn (exchange-point-and-mark)))) (if (and input-file (file-exists-p input-file) (not (if (boundp 'org-babel--debug-input) (progn org-babel--debug-input)))) (progn (delete-file input-file))) (if (and error-file (file-exists-p error-file)) (progn (if (< 0 (file-attribute-size (file-attributes error-file))) (progn (save-current-buffer (set-buffer (get-buffer-create error-buffer)) (let (...) (or ... ...) (format-insert-file error-file nil) (goto-char ...)) (current-buffer)))) (delete-file error-file))) exit-status)
  org-babel--shell-command-on-region(1 7 "bash" #<buffer  *Org-Babel Error*>)
  (setq exit-code (org-babel--shell-command-on-region (point-min) (point-max) cmd err-buff))
...
  org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c(nil)
  funcall-interactively(org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c nil)
  call-interactively(org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c nil nil)
  command-execute(org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c)
```

### Emacs version

```
GNU Emacs 27.1 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, X toolkit, cairo version 1.16.0, Xaw scroll bars)
```

### `*Messages*` buffer

This is what is in my `*Messages*`, from launching emacs, to hitting the error:

```
For information about GNU Emacs and the GNU system, type C-h C-a.
Starting new Ispell process /run/current-system/sw/bin/aspell with en_GB dictionary...done
Setting up indent for shell type bash
Indentation variables are now local.
Indentation setup for shell type bash
t
Setting up indent for shell type bash
Indentation variables are now local.
Indentation setup for shell type bash
executing Bash code block...
Tramp: Opening connection for skid@127.0.0.1 using ssh...
Tramp: Sending command ‘exec ssh -l skid -p 2221 -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPath='tramp.%C' -o ControlPersist=no -e none 127.0.0.1’
Tramp: Waiting for prompts from remote shell...done
Tramp: Found remote shell prompt on ‘127.0.0.1’
Tramp: Opening connection for skid@127.0.0.1 using ssh...done
Tramp: Encoding local file ‘/tmp/tramp.pKJ3ih’ using ‘base64-encode-region’...done
Tramp: Decoding remote file ‘/ssh:skid@127.0.0.1#2221:/tmp/ob-input-xciyut’ using ‘base64 -d -i >%s’...done
Tramp: Encoding local file ‘/tmp/tramp.TfMrVo’ using ‘base64-encode-region’...done
Tramp: Decoding remote file ‘/ssh:skid@127.0.0.1#2221:/tmp/ob-error-PpTmjP’ using ‘base64 -d -i >%s’...done
Tramp: Encoding local file ‘/tmp/tramp.5JTsQ8’ using ‘base64-encode-region’...done
Tramp: Decoding remote file ‘/ssh:skid@127.0.0.1#2221:/tmp/ob-input-xciyut’ using ‘base64 -d -i >%s’...done
Wrote /ssh:skid@127.0.0.1#2221:/tmp/ob-input-xciyut
Entering debugger...
```

### Temp files

The following (empty) file is created when going through the above steps:

```bash
~$ ssh -X -p2221 skid@localhost 'ls -ltr /tmp/ob-*'
-rw-r--r-- 1 skid users 0 Feb  5 09:29 /tmp/ob-error-PpTmjP
```

From `watch -n.1 ssh -X -p2221 skid@localhost 'ls -ltr /tmp/ob-*'` it seems like nothing else is created. At least it wasn't picked up by me watching this command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Tramp keeps its persistent data in `~/.emacs.d/tramp`. You can either remove this file prior starting Emacs, or trash its contents by `M-x tramp-cleanup-all-connections` any time.
2. I've tried to reproduce your scenario. I've used my own remote machine (obviously), with a non-standard port. In order to minimize interference with other packages, I have started Emacs via `emacs -Q -l org -l ob-shell`. No error, it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce it myself any more.

After repeating this tens of times (closing emacs, restarting remote), I tried switching the remote to the default ssh port (22), and it then worked when not specifying a port. It then worked when specifying port 22 in the properties, and also when moving remote back to port 2221.

I keep the org file on git, and the remote host is a vm running nixos (https://gitlab.com/kidmose/dotfiles/-/tree/master/nixos/vms/htb-box) so i have no idea how this can happen. Does tramp store some state that can get messed up?